# Hide "User is typing..." in WhatsApp

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, chat

In `WhatsApp` Group chat, when other person is typing when I am actively looking at the group conversation chat, I could see who is typing at the other end.

That conversely also means, when I am typing in a group chat, other people too can see me typing.

I checked the [FAQ](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/23776567) Section of `WhatsApp`. Could not found any settings mentioned for this.

**Is there a way to disable showing "Me typing..." to other people in a group chat when I am typing?** Wanted to surprise them by my post directly :)

Comment: I am not aware of such a feature yet in WhatsApp.

Comment: I don't think this is possible: first because even if you turn off the 'last seen' option and write on a normal chat the other person can see 'John Doe is typing...'; second because groups have a lower privacy than normal chats (they can see if you read a message and when). EDIT: found articles and forum posts that confirm my idea: it is not possible unless you turn off mobile data while typing or installa a modded version of WA (if they still exist/work).

Answer (score -1):

You could try a modded version of WhatsApp, there are many of them nowadays and are constantly being updated too.

I have tried a few **for research purposes only** and Gb WhatsApp seems to have a bunch of extra options with the ability to block features like:

- typing status,
- online status,
- and blue ticks to mention a few...

  Take a look here: [WhatsApp modded versions](http://www.whatsappmods.net/) for more information.